# How to get the URL of the xml which is in my Project?

Tags: asp.net, xml, path

i am new to asp.net.
I am having one `xml` file in my `web site`.
   I would like to use that `XML` file in `code behind`
   I would like to use `relative path` Only. How to get that Path instead of `Absolute path`.

Comment: check the asnwer as do according to it to read file

Answer (score 2):

You can read your xml file in project easily like this

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sample.xml"));
```

use `Server.MapPath` to read xml file in you project as in above code

---

there is following way to get reelative path of file

1.A site-root relative path, which is resolved against the site root.

The following example path assumes that an Images folder is located under the Web site root.

```
<img src="/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

2.A relative path that is resolved against the current page path.

```
<img src="Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

3.Arelative path that is resolved as a peer of the current page path.

```
<img src="../Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

Check MSDN for detail : [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make path of xml starting from the root direct your xml accessible. You can use `~` in the path that will be root of you site.

```
"~/yourfolder/yourxml.xml"
```

Relative path from root using

```
 "/yourfolder/yourxml.xml"
```

If you want to make relative path with respect to your current page

```
"yourfolder/yourxml.xml"
```

You can read more about relative paths **[here](http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/dgm/2120/IN/steinja/lessons/06/06_04.html)**

Comment: I want to read that `xml` file in Code behind i.e i have written my code like this.........dsData.Load("~myXML.xml");     It gives file not found

Comment: and myXML.xml file and code behind file included in project solution folder